# How to turn the command output in a multiselect list

Tags: bash

I want to make a multiselect in Bash.
At the moment I am using the following syntax

```
PS3='Please choose the app you want to install: '

select app in X Y Quit
do
    case $app in
        "X")
            ...
            break;;
        "Y")
            ...
            break;;
        "Quit")
           echo "We're done"
           exit 0;;
        *)
    esac
done
```

`X` and `Y` are now hard coded but I want to generate this list automatically based on the output of another command which returns a list. Like so:

```
ANCAP/ANCAP-Rescue-app
ANCAP/ANCAP-Rescue-app-store
... and so one
```

Is this possible in pure Bash?

Comment: please update the question to show an example of this 'list' that's generated by your other command

Comment: if the `select` list is to be generated dynamically, does that mean you also need the `case` options to be generated dynamically?  or should the `case` statement remain hardcoded for `X` / `Y` / `Quit`?  please update the question with your answer

Comment: case should also be generated dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample list of apps:

```
$ cat list.dat
ANCAP/ANCAP-Rescue-app
ANCAP/ANCAP-Rescue-app-store
```

General design:

- load the list of apps into an array
- replace the `case` block with an `if/elif/else` block

One approach:

```
$ cat app.sh
#!/usr/bin/bash

unset      applist                                # clear variable
mapfile -t applist < list.dat                     # load lines from 'list.dat' into applist[] array

echo ""
PS3='Please choose the app you want to install: '

select app in "${applist[@]}" 'Quit'
do
    if [[ -z "${app}" ]]                          # invalid option selected
    then
        echo "Sorry, try again"
    elif [[ "${app}" = 'Quit' ]]
    then
        echo "We're done"
        break
    else
        echo "do something with ${app} ..."
        break
    fi
done
```

Taking for a test drive:

```
$ ./app.sh

1) ANCAP/ANCAP-Rescue-app        3) Quit
2) ANCAP/ANCAP-Rescue-app-store
Please choose the app you want to install: 1
do something with ANCAP/ANCAP-Rescue-app ...

$ ./app.sh

1) ANCAP/ANCAP-Rescue-app        3) Quit
2) ANCAP/ANCAP-Rescue-app-store
Please choose the app you want to install: 2
do something with ANCAP/ANCAP-Rescue-app-store ...

$ ./app.sh

1) ANCAP/ANCAP-Rescue-app        3) Quit
2) ANCAP/ANCAP-Rescue-app-store
Please choose the app you want to install: 4
Sorry, try again
Please choose the app you want to install: 3
We're done
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can save the result of a command into a variable and then reference the variable in the `select` statement. Be careful not to quote the `$RESULT` as `select` then will interpret it as *one* option.

```bash
RESULT="$(echo X Y)" # Just as example, could also cat from a file

PS3='Please choose the app you want to install: '
select app in $RESULT Quit
do
    case $app in
        "X")
            break;;
        "Y")
            break;;
        "Quit")
           echo "We're done"
           exit 0;;
        *)
    esac
done
```

You can also use command substitution directly on the select statement.